# HashSet Count Comparison Java

Tags: java, hashset

What I want to achieve is to count the numbers of the string that has the same value from the inputs.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

Set group1 = new HashSet();
Set group2 = new HashSet();
Set self = new HashSet();

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter birt month " + i + ": ");
    group1.add(reader.next());
}

for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter birt month " + i + ": ");
    group2.add(reader.next());
}
System.out.print("Enter your birth month: ");
self.add(reader.next());

if (group1.contains(self) || group2.contains(self)) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println("You have the same birth month with " + count + " of your classmate.");
```

But I didn't get the value that I should have, what I've got is that even though the `group1` or `group2` has the same value as the `HashSet` named `self` the counter doesn't goes up, it stays 0 and i don't know why. Any tips or please help me how to do this. Also I tried to vice versa the if statement into `self.contains(group1) || self.contains(group2);` to determine whether the self has the same group1 or group2

SOLVED!!

All I need was just to use `containsAll` which will read the set if `group1` and `group2` has it in the set named `self`

Comment: You are not updating `self` in any way. It will always be empty.

Comment: Ow, I forgot to add. I have somthing like this `System.out.print("Enter your Birth Month: ");` then update it by. `self.add(reader.next());`

Comment: But still the same prob tho.

Comment: Can you update your full code? Give an example of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Okay, I edited it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your problem is this.

`group1.contains(self)` checks if an object `self` is present inside group1 which is not the case here.

Here, you want to compare it to a Set `self` which is a Collection.

Change  `group1.contains(self)` to `group1.containsAll(self)`.

Comment: Just an addition to this answer: this problem was caused by using a raw type for the collections. If they had been declared with the types of their items then the compiler would have complained.

Comment: Ow, Thank you for this. this was the only thing I have been looking for. But one last question, even though I have typed 2 same strings, it only gives me 1

Comment: @JiggyPalconit Dont get your doubt. Can your clarify input and expected output? `count++` increments only once. You need to separate both the if conditions if you want the output as 2.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Sorry for the trouble sir.

Answer (score 2):

Also, One more issue I found is, your incrementing count variable only once if. What I would suggest is, use 2 if conditions like below,

```
    int count = 0;
    if (group1.containsAll(self)) {
        count++;
    }

    if (group2.containsAll(self)) {
        count++;
    }
```

The above condition takes care if both Set's had "**self**"

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Anyways, Thanks :)